Python using oracledb to connect to Oracle database with Pandas DataFrame Error: "pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection)"
I am pretty new to Python and even newer to Pandas and am hoping for some guidance
My company has an on-prem DEV Oracle database that I am trying to connect to using Python & Pandas. After some searching I found that the Python package "oracledb" was recommended to be used.
Using VS code .IPYNB I have the following chunks of code that seem to work with no errors
# python -m pip install --upgrade pandas
import oracledb
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection = oracledb.connect(user="TEST", password="TESTING", dsn="TESTDB:1234/TEST")

print("Connected")
print(connection)

The above code seems to run just fine which is great
I then run the below code as a quick test
cursor=connection.cursor()
query_test='select * from dm_cnf_date where rownum < 2'

for row in cursor.execute(query_test):
    print(row)

This returns a tuple with a row of data so far so good, looks like I can connect to the database and run a query.
Next I wanted to get the data into a Pandas dataframe and this is where I got stuck
I tried this code
df = pd.read_sql(sql=query_test, con=connection)

Which then I get hit with the following error

:1: UserWarning: pandas only supports
SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or
sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please
consider using SQLAlchemy.   df = pd.read_sql(sql=query_test,
con=connection)

I was loosely trying to follow this article ("Read data as pandas DataFrame"): https://kontext.tech/article/1019/python-read-data-from-oracle-database
but it didnt seem to work.
I tried to take a look at the sqlalchemy site here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.oracledb
Which I tried to rewrite my code a bit as follows
conn_url="oracle+oracledb://TEST:TESTING@TESTDB:1234/TEST"
engine=create_engine(conn_url)

df = pd.read_sql(sql=query_test, con=engine)

And I get hit with another error

OperationalError: DPY-6003: SID "TEST" is not
registered with the listener at host "TESTDB" port
1234. (Similar to ORA-12505)

Just looking to connect to an Oracle DB and grab data into a Pandas dataframe but keep hitting a wall
Any insight would be very much appreciated

Just saying: Warnings are not errors. Do you get a DataFrame back despite the warning?

I think searching for the keyword ORA-12505 would help you understand the issue in detail. I guess you need to modify the Oracle DB setting for the current database.

@GordThompson - No dataframe it was actually just a full on error and unable to connect at all

@djmoon13 - Yup I tried to take a look at that Oracle error and it mentioned something about the TNS does not know of the SID, but the funny thing was that I was able to connect fine with the oracledb package so I initially didnt think it was the SID. It looks like SQLAlchemy defaults to wanting to using SID but I was actually using the Oracle Service Name

Try either of:
#oracledb.defaults.arraysize = 1000 # Tune for big queries

with oracledb.connect(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs) as connection:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
       cursor.execute("select * from emp")
       col_names = [c.name for c in cursor.description]
       data = cursor.fetchall()
       df = pandas.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)
       print(df)

or
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    'oracle+oracledb://',
    thick_mode=None,
    connect_args={
        "user": un,
        "password": pw,
        "dsn": cs
    }
    #, echo=True  # SQLAlchemy tracing / logging / debugging
    )

emp_sql = "select * from emp"
df_emp = pd.read_sql(emp_sql, engine)
print(df_emp)

The latter is slower. You can enable the tracing and see the number of queries that are executed internally by SQLAlchemy.
Regarding the ORA-12505 error using:
"oracle+oracledb://TEST:TESTING@TESTDB:1234/TEST"

you probably needed to use:
"oracle+oracledb://TEST:TESTING@TESTDB:1234?service_name=TEST"

see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/oracle.html#dialect-oracle-oracledb-connect
Back in the old days, 'system identifiers' (SIDs) were commonly used for connecting to Oracle DB.  SQLAlchemy defaults to use these in its syntax.  However most DBs are now connected to via a 'service name', hence the need for the extra connection keyword.  See the note in the SQLAlchemy doc:

Note that although the SQLAlchemy URL syntax hostname:port/dbname looks like Oracle’s Easy Connect syntax, it is different. SQLAlchemy’s URL requires a system identifier (SID) for the dbname component

You should continue using your 'service name' TEST, and not try to find what SID to use.

Appreciate the detailed reply! You were right I needed to use the additional ?service_name= syntax and got it to finally connect. Question please - In your second example I noticed you used an f string (f'oracle+oracledb://') without any parameters? How does that f-string work? I am used to seeing something like the following [create_engine(f'oracle+cx_oracle://{user}:{pwd}@{dsn}', echo=True)] but your method looks much cleaner

My (now removed) f-string was a hang-over from other tests; it had no effect because there was nothing to substiture.  I prefer using connect_args because it is more flexible, lets other python-oracledb driver connection options be passed, and avoids issues when special characters are used in the password.

Thank you so much for your patient explanation! I actually found your article on "Medium" as well! Wow its such a treat/honor to chat with you @Christopher Jones!
